# Node.js with Typescript and Mysql Testing routes mock services

Tags: mysql, node.js, typescript, testing, repository-pattern

I am using node.js with typescript to build a web api. For the database I am using mariadb (mysql). I have build the project using the repository pattern + unit of work (I am not a .NET dev but I am working in a company that uses .NET). 
  I am trying to write tests and so far I have been able to write them for the domain models and the services using chai and the typemoq library for my mocks. I guess for the repositories will be also doable. Where I am facing problems (for now) is in the routes where I am using my services. Is it possible to test a route and mock the service? I ve seen many node tutorials where they write a test for the route but they just check the response without mocking anything. Isn't that similar to an integration test and not a unit test? How would someone apply TDD to node?

Here's an example:

```
router.post('/register', (req, res, next) => {

try {
    let newUser = <RegisterUserDTO>req.body;
    let uow = <IUnitOfWork>req.uow;
    let userRepository = new UserRepository(uow);
    let userService: IUserService = new UserService(userRepository);

    userService.getByUsername(newUser.username)
        .then((user:User) => {

            if(!user) {
                userService.getByEmail(newUser.email).then(user => {
                    if(!user) {
                        userService.insertUser(newUser)
                            .then((result) => {
                                res.json({
                                            success: true, 
                                            msg: "User registered",
                                            userId: result.insertId 
                                        });
                            })
                            .catch(err => {
                                res.json({ errorMessage: err.message, errorStackTrace: err.stack });
                            });
                    }else {
                        res.json({ success: false, msg: "This email already exists" });
                    }
                });
            }else {
                res.json({ success: false, msg: "This username already exists" });
            }
        })

}
catch(err) {
    res.json({ errorMessage: err.message, errorStackTrace: err.stack });
}
```

});

How would I mock the userService and test this route? 
Is this a "wrong" way to use node?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Did you endup coming up with a solution? If not I can show you the tools/approach that I use?

Comment: Yes I did but please let me know your approach. What I did is to create a fake server and pass any dependency in its constructor. So by using sinon.js I create the stubs/mocks that I need and feed them to the fake server.

Comment: I use sinon as well. I'll post an example using your code later this evening.

Answer (score -1):

To make this easier to test I would push more logic into your service and divide the responsibilities of the route and the service. Having lots of if statements and even a repository creation inside your route will make it very hard to test and gives the route greater responsibility than just routing requests and responses.

Heres one way to structure it.

**user.route.js**

```
const userService = require("../services/user.services.js")

router.post("/register",function(req){
    var potentialUser = webAdapter.getUserFromRequest(req)
    var response      = userService.register(potentialUser) //returns a promsie
                        webWriterUtility.json(response)
```

**UserRoute's Responsibility**

If you analyze the code above the responsibility of the route is no-longer to determine the appropriate response message, check if the user exists, etc etc. Its job is to take a response from the userService and send that to the user. This simplifies what I need to test. Since in a route test I'm only concerned with whats happening immediately inside the route, I can stub out the userService.register entirely. Whether userService returns a promise resolve or promise rejection doesn't matter, only that the route handles those scenarios correctly.

The code above and the URL "/user/register" could be tested with sinon.js pretty easily. Node only loads a "required" module once so in your unit test for the user route you can load userService, add stubs to the register function and then when UserRoute loads userService it gets the stub function.

```
var registerStub = sinon.stub(userService,"registerUser") 
registerStub.callsFake(()=>{
      return Promise.resolve(userResponse)
    })
```

Here is an example User Route test using the stubbing approach

**user.routes.test.js**

```
const superTest   = require('supertest')
const expect      = require('chai').expect
const assert      = require("chai").assert
const sinon       = require("sinon")    
const userService = require("../services/user.services")
const app         = require("../app').app

describe("User Routes: ",function(){
  var registerStub = sinon.stub(userService,"registerUser")    

  beforeEach(()=>{
    registerStub.callsFake(()=>{
      return Promise.resolve(userResponse)
    })
  })
  afterEach(()=>{
    registerStub.restore()
  })

  it("can get register a user",function(done){
      superTest(app).post("/user/register")
      .set("XXXXXXX")
      .send("email=sfsfsf&firstName=xsdfsfs")
      .expect(200).then( response =>{
        assert(response.text == EXPECTED_RESPONSE)
        done()

      }).catch(e=>{
        //TEST FAILED
        console.log(e)
        done(e)
      })
  })
})
```

The test above is a trip wire ensuring the user route acts as an event handler on the URL "/user/register". Its not a test of the logic inside the userService. UserRoute and UserService have 2 isolated responsibilities in this design.

**UserService's Responsibility**

UserService.register returns a promise that resolves to a response object or rejects with an error object. Another utility class has the responsibility of converting that result to status code 500 if the promise is a rejection, or JSON if the promise is resolved. Testing the code below can be done using the earlier stubbing method to mock your database client/module to make it look like users already exist and then confirm the appropriate message is returned.

**user.serivice.js**

```
    module.exports.register = function(req){
    var resolve;
    var reject;
    var promise = new Promise((resolveTemp,rejectTemp) => {
      resolve = resolveTemp
      reject  = rejectTemp
    })

    let newUser = <RegisterUserDTO>req.body;

        getByUsername(newUser.username)
            .then((user:User) => {        
                if(!user) {
                    getByEmail(newUser.email).then(user => {
                        if(!user) {
                            insertUser(newUser)
                                .then((result) => {
                                    resolve({
                                                success: true, 
                                                msg: "User registered",
                                                userId: result.insertId 
                                            });
                                })
                                .catch(err => {
                                    reject(err);
                                });
                        }else {
                            resolve({ success: false, msg: "This email already exists" });
                        }
                    });
                }else {
                     resolve({ success: false, msg: "This username already exists" });
                }
            })

    return promise
}
```

You can detach the user service's need to know about requests and responses by wrapping the results of operations as promises. For me an error object causes everything to abort so reject(err) is usually enough but you could use `reject({message:"ssfsfs",code:500,error:err})` or create an `ApplicationError` type that you use for all your rejections. This is a neat way of getting errors to bubble up from the business logic to the HTTP layer without having to pass Request and Response objects deeply into your business logic.